# Maven site plugin or one of it's dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: maven, maven-3, dependency-management, nexus, sonatype

I am in a restricted network which doesn't allow access to dowloading files from the internet, as a result we have a local Nexus server running.

Whitelisting proxies is not an option

I need to update our common java libraries repository, I have managed to create a process for uploading new artifacts to nexus.

1. Use a settings.xml which allows connection to central
2. Download all new artifacts using a pom with the new dependencies declared
3. This downloads all jars/poms to `~/.m2/repository`. I have a python script which copies the contents of repository to another temporary directory, it then walks this directory and runs `mvn deploy:deploy-file` for each jar/pom it comes across.
4. I then switch my settings.xml with one which only allows connection to nexus and not central.

In theory this sounded great but when I run `mvn dependency:resolve` with the local settings.xml I get the following

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom (4 KB at 23.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/22/maven-plugins-22.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/22/maven-plugins-22.pom (13 KB at 187.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/21/maven-parent-21.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/21/maven-parent-21.pom (26 KB at 357.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/apache/10/apache-10.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/apache/10/apache-10.pom (15 KB at 147.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.jar
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.jar (25 KB at 325.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom (7 KB at 100.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/23/maven-plugins-23.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/23/maven-plugins-23.pom (9 KB at 149.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/22/maven-parent-22.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/22/maven-parent-22.pom (30 KB at 215.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/apache/11/apache-11.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/apache/11/apache-11.pom (15 KB at 278.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.jar
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.jar (27 KB at 355.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom (6 KB at 91.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.jar
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.jar (27 KB at 494.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom (21 KB at 312.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/24/maven-plugins-24.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom (5 KB at 81.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/12/maven-plugins-12.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/12/maven-plugins-12.pom (12 KB at 47.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/9/maven-parent-9.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/9/maven-parent-9.pom (33 KB at 305.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom (5 KB at 75.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.jar
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.jar (24 KB at 451.4 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom (15 KB at 185.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/16/maven-plugins-16.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/16/maven-plugins-16.pom (13 KB at 252.9 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/15/maven-parent-15.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/15/maven-parent-15.pom (24 KB at 366.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/apache/6/apache-6.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/apache/6/apache-6.pom (13 KB at 137.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.jar
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.jar (204 KB at 2193.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom (12 KB at 116.5 KB/sec)
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.pom
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.pom (10 KB at 116.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/release/maven-release/2.3.2/maven-release-2.3.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.3.2
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (834 B at 6.7 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (3 KB at 20.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.776 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-06-17T09:50:07+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:24 in http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

It has problems resolving dependencies for a number of maven plugins, I have tried looking through the plugin poms and checking to see I have the dependencies in Nexus, but I'm obviously still missing some.

Is there an easy way to see which dependencies it can't resolve?

Here's my settings.xml

```xml
<settings>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror> 
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://localhost:8082/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <servers>  
        <server>    
            <id>deployment</id>    
            <username>admin</username>    
            <password>admin123</password>  
        </server>
    </servers>
    <profiles>
       <profile> 
           <id>nexus</id> 
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile> 
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles> 
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: You are in a restricted network which is not unusual..But your nexus does not offer the correct file to get a build working...which means your nexus must be able to download those files from the internet (Maven Central).

Comment: Yes, and the files Nexus doesn't hold are downloaded from a machine which does have access to the internet, these are then deployed to Nexus

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The clue was in the original message

```
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

So running `mvn dependency:resolve -X` gave me more specific details

edit: An example of a more specific message it gives

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.708 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-06-18T11:15:26+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project mavenproject1: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xxx:mavenproject1:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.hamcrest:hamcrest-parent:jar:1.3 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project mavenproject1: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xxx:mavenproject1:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.hamcrest:hamcrest-parent:jar:1.3 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:221)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:257)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xxx:mavenproject1:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.hamcrest:hamcrest-parent:jar:1.3 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:211)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.hamcrest:hamcrest-parent:jar:1.3 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:205)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.hamcrest:hamcrest-parent:jar:1.3 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.hamcrest:hamcrest-parent:jar:1.3 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        ... 27 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: It is great that you answered your own question. Unfortunately the answer is not very helpful for other users as it does not contain these "specific details". Do you mind adding them?

Comment: @gillesB added for you